# Angular forms validators

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form where I display an error when the field is invalid directly in the html. Can we put this error message in the ts.file using the Validators ?

Thanks.

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
 <mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Nom</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="nom"/>
   <div *ngIf="form.get('nom')?.invalid"> error </div> // display this error in ts.file
 </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**ts.file**

```
formulaire(): FormGroup {
 this.form = this.fb.group({
 nom: ['', [Validators.required]]
 })
}
```

Comment: Looks fine, you can do that

Comment: yes it works, but how to display this msg in the ts file and not in the html directly if I have u error?

Comment: ... inside the file alike: ` validate() { if(this.form.valid) console.log('Form valid') ... or if(this.form.get('nom').valid .... ` ...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Angular Doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#initializing-form-controls), you can't set the error message directly when you create a FormControl. That's normal, it must be done into `html` template.

Otherwise, you can do a quick fix, but I don't recommend it at all.
Maybe you need to review your purpose : Why do you need to manage error message into `typescript` file ?